# USB Drive is not detecting and is in read only mode with error NTFS signature is missing

Tags: usb-drive, ntfs, readonly, corruption

command :

sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb

Output :

/dev/sdb:

setting readonly to 0 (off)

***readonly      =  1 (on)***

By any chance it will be turned off ? If yes how can we?

**Issue:**

USB is not detected. Unable to format the disk and partition.

[image]

[image]

**And unable to create partition using gparted-> Device -> create partition -> msdos**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely the USB drive has failed. Get any existing data off it if you can, then throw it away and get a new one.